# Haskell coding-style: map, fmap or <$>?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, coding-style

Is there any reason to prefer one of the following notations over the others or is this simply a matter of preference?

```
map toLower "FOO"

fmap toLower "FOO"

toLower <$> "FOO"
```

As an aside: I realize that `<$>` is the same as `` `fmap` ``. Am I right in the assumption that `map` is just a less general form of `fmap`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As you say, `map` is a less general form of `fmap`. If you know you have a list then I would use `map` as it makes the code clearer and if you make a mistake the error message is likely to be less confusing. However to a large extent it's a matter of preference.

`(<$>)` is the same as `fmap`. Until GHC 7.10 it wasn't exported by the Prelude so wasn't available by default - but even with older GHC versions it's easy to import from `Data.Functor` or `Control.Applicative` and these days it's pretty much the standard way to do this.

Comment: And `liftM` is the same as `fmap`, except it is overloaded on `Monad` instead of `Functor`.

Comment: [**`liftA`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#liftA) as well, generalized for [**`Applicative`** Functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html)

Comment: `<$>` is exported by the prelude in recent versions.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with Ganesh that `map` is clearer for lists.  I use `<$>` over `fmap`, unless it is partially applied.  So I'd use `fmap reverse` to declare a function that reverses all elements of some functor but if I have all the arguments available (e.g. if I'm writing a line in a `do` block) I tend to use the operator form: `reverse <$> f x`

Comment: I often use `fmap` in infix notation, e.g.: `reverse \`fmap\` x`, since `fmap` is in the Prelude, so that I don't have to import Control.Applicative. Then if I need partial application, I end up writing: `f = (reverse \`fmap\`)`

Comment: I find it looks better to just use the `fmap` function plain and simple (prefix), but maybe that's just me… I do use `<$>` when I'm also using `<*>`, though.